# How to find a specif string inside a bunch of strings? Both inside different cells

Tags: python, pandas

How can I find if one of these words from a column A is inside of one of these columns B and C?

column A) `df['all_types'] = 'spray, protetor, toalha, esfoliante'`

column B) `df['make_sempre'] = 'limpador-facial,esfoliante,hidratante-labial,hidratante,serum'`

column C) `df['skin_sempre'] = 'corretivo,batom,produtos-sombrancelha,pinceis,mascara-cilios,iluminador,gloss,blush,delineador'`

I've done it using a loop inside a loop inside a loop. And it worked.
But with hundreds of thousands of rows, this was impossible.

I've split these words into separated columns, and then applied a loop to compare each column with the others.

I'm using python and pandas

Comment: What do you expect to be returned, a Boolean or the word?

Comment: I suggest reviewing [pandas check for words from one column in another column](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+check+for+words+from+one+column+in+another+column+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ALeKk022skyAp9Aw6eQK93hY4UTraX_knw:1597864763541&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFxoSN_qfrAhUsCTQIHVW8DKUQrQIoBHoECAcQBQ&biw=1920&bih=975). There are a number of questions with answers, dealing with this issue.

Comment: I want it to return a boolean.. 
I didn't find a solution to my specific question. So I choose to split column A into column_A0, column_A1, and so on.
And then compare 1 word from column A0 with many from column B or C.
Not many with many.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using set differences, so each column being a set of words or combine columns B and C to be one set, then get the difference.

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: Make them sets first
`A = set(df['all_types'].split(",")) 
B = df['make_sempre'].split(",")
C = df['skin_sempre'].split(",")
BplusC = set(B + C)`

Then check if the intersection returns empty
`if (A.intersection(BplusC)):
   return True
else:
   return False`

Comment: Awesome! 
Didn't know about that. Very useful.
Thanks